# Create columns that autoincrement with name in a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment

I know that this might seem like a strange question, but let me try and explain it. I have a database table called 'plan' and in it the first column is called 'username' and the columns after it are called 'question1', 'question2' and so on. I now need to add a hundred or so more columns named like this, but it would be nice to have a sql statement that would automatically do that for me.

I know this wasn't set up in the best way, but if you have a solution, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any SQL command or feature that would do this automatically; sure you can generate the alter table statements and add the columns programmatically; however, your design would be terribly flawed.

Instead of adding columns, you should create a table containing the question, the user_id (or username, whatever is the PK) to hold the records. If you need to identify a question by number (or ID), simply add another column called question_id.

Answer (score -1):

Write the query in sql to excel. Seperate the incrementing number. Drag down until excel row 100. Hard to explain but i guess you ll figure it out. You'll have 100 incrementing add column sql statements. copy paste run it on a query tool.

Comment: -1 I am sorry but this is a terrible advice. One does not create 100 columns in a table just because one needs to store 100 questions.

Comment: He already admits that he isnt doing something normal. I m just focusing on solving his question. Should I suggest a book on RDBMS theory???

Comment: Frankly, that'd be a better answer. The idea here is not to answer blindly because the user says he wants to do something -specially if it's clearly flawed,- but rather point him in the right direction or even suggesting him to read an article or a book on good practices.